comfyui: python torch/resizing image - height adjusts width and width adjusts color?
First time here, I am new to python and trying to resize an image for a ComfyUI node using python
import torch
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
from PIL import Image

class ImageResize:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def INPUT_TYPES(cls):
        return {
            "required": {
                "image": ("IMAGE",),
                "height": ("INT", {"min": 1}),
                "width": ("INT", {"min": 1}),
            },
        }

    RETURN_TYPES = ("IMAGE",)
    FUNCTION = "resize_image"
    CATEGORY = "ImageProcessing"

    def resize_image(self, image, height, width):
        input_image = image
        resized_image = TF.resize(input_image, (height, width))
        return (resized_image,)


Using the above, when I adjust the height, the width changes, and when I adjust the width,
int of 1 shows cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1), |u1
int of 2 shows a black and white image
int of 3 shows a full colour image
int of 4 shows a dimmed colour image
5 or higher throws the same error as 1 with the last value incrementing to 5 or higher ie: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 5), |u1
What am I doing wrong?
not sure why height is adjusting the width and the width doing something completely different

Hi! To help others answer your question, provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example, which in this case would be example code on how you are trying to use ImageResize.resize_image.

example would be load any jpg image with RGB color and try to change height and width

Yes, that much is obvious from the original question. This by itself does not help others to reproduce your problem, as the actual offending code is not shown. Depending on the choice of libraries, functions and preprocessing steps used, your image array can have different data types and memory layouts, which is relevant information regarding your problem. Please do read the link provided in my previous comment.

Understood, excuse the ignorance as new to all of this. I am running a node in ComfyUI and webui for stable diffusion, i am using a load image node to load a jpg or png image which is then passed onto my node which resizes it, this is then passed onto a preview image node which takes the output from my node and displays it. I don't have access to the code for the load image node nor the preview image node.

No worries! There is a learning curve to all of this. When using 3rd party libraries, it is good practice to check if they have a public github repository - which is the case with ComfyUI. This usually helps with debugging, as you can look at the source.

The problem here is that torchvision and ComfyUI use different memory layouts when handling image data. When representing colour images as multidimensional arrays, there are two commonly used approaches: channel-last format (image arrays are of shape [H, W, C]) used in libraries like PIL, opencv and tensorflow, and channel-first format ([C, H, W]) used mostly by torch and torchvision.
If we look at the implementation for LoadImage, we see that the images are opened with PIL.Image.open, so the resulting array will be in channel-last format. In your custom node, you are using the resize operator of torchvision, which expects its inputs to be channel-first.
The resize operation itself just an interpolation, and can handle inputs of arbitrary shape. In your case, however, when you pass an image with the wrong memory layout, trying to change the height will change the width, and trying to change the width will change the channels. Hence the weird colours you are seeing - resizing the "width" to 4 will add an alpha (transparency) channel to the image making it appear dimmed.
For the desired behaviour, you need to modify the image to match the expected input shape of torchvision.Resize, e.g. transpose the array to be channel-first.
# note that this example expects images to always have a batch
# dimension and a colour channel
def resize_image(self, image, height, width):
    # [B, H, W, C] -> [B, C, H, W]
    input_image = image.permute((0, 3, 1, 2))
    resized_image = TF.resize(input_image, (height, width))
    # [B, C, H, W] -> [B, H, W, C]
    resized_image = resized_image.permute((0, 2, 3, 1))
    return (resized_image,)

This is a good example why the full stack trace should be provided when asking questions, as the underlying problem was not in your implementation of the node, but in the discrepancy in how ComfyUI and torchvision handle images.

Thank you very much, that works. permute function reorders things, nice

just like to say, thank you again, I can not emphasise how valuable that bit of information has been for me, many little projects stalled not knowing this info.

No worries, happy to help! The software side of computer vision is full of small caveats like these that you sort of just need to know, it'll get easier over time.
